# Draft document owner can't see their document after migration

Tags: document, approval, draft

I have a SharePoint 2010 site which contains a number of documents that are draft and have document approval turned on so that only approvers and the document author can see drafts.  After copying the site using a sharepoint migration tool the document author can't see their document - as site owner I can see that the version history has been correctly copied and also that the author still appears in the 'created by' and 'modified by' fields.  Apparently this is a limitation with the SharePoint migration APIs that the draft owner ID cannot be copied.  Is there a way to assign a new author to the document so that they can see the draft after migration?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the `Author` for the documents than you can use the **PowerShell** command mentioned below.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c”)

$SPSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite(http://yoursitename/site1/site2/)

$SPWeb = $SPSite.OpenWeb()

$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists[“Your List”]

$SPListItemCollection = $SPList.Items

foreach ($ListItem in $SPListItemCollection)

{

$SPFieldUserValue=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue ($SPWeb,10, “domainname\username”)

$ListItem[“Author”] = $SPFieldUserValue
$ListItem.Update()

}

$SPWeb.Update()
```